# Guidance for diagnosing {"message":"An error has occurred."}

Tags: azure-mobile-services

Can someone point me in the direction of instructions for working out what has gone wrong with my Mobile Service App. It was working fine with a couple of simple tables. I then extended the data model using code first and migrations and now all I get when enter a url such as:

```
http://xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/tables/firm?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0
```

is

```
{"message":"An error has occurred."}
```

I have now removed all new tables/data objects and controllers so that only one exists for a single table called "Firm" which has a single string property. I have switch OFF authentication/authorization in the Azure portal but I still get the same error.

I have tried both CustomErrors=Off and CustomErrors=RemoteOnly in the debug web config. I am publishing a debug build.

I have tried switching on logging and remote debugging etc in Azure but am unable to work out what is broken. I have tried remote debugging with a break point in my FirmController GetAllFirms method but error occurs before that point.

How do I get more useful information about what the problem is?

Comment: You can [enable diagnostics for your web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) and check if more useful information are written in logs.

Comment: A bit more information. I have narrowed the issue down to something to do with the data side of things. I cleared the database out, reset code first migrations and then rebuilt everything with a single table and controller. Published and it worked.

I have then added a second data object/table and controller. Added a new code first migration and published. I can see the new table is created on the backend and seeded but the API has now broken and just returns the "An error has occurred" message. This happens for both the original table and the new table.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this one myself. In fact now that I know what it is the answer was staring at me from the build output.

The issue was that when extending my model I referenced a .NET Standard 2.0 class library containing some enum definitions that are common to both the backend and the client.

I did not notice the warning that some assembly versions needed binding redirects added to web config. Double click on the warning message and VS2017 will add the necessary entries to web.config for you.

For more details see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481) on github.

I never did manage to get behind the {"message":"An error has occurred."} though. I solved this by rebuilding my backend project one step at a time and it was after adding the reference to the .NET standard project than I noticed the "Consider app.config remapping of assembly ..." messages in the build output window.